# Ubuntu doesnt detect one partition on dual boot with windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, detect

I have windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in my dell inspiron 5010.

I have these three partitions in my lap. C (windows sys),D,F. I have installed ubuntu alongside but when i log in to ubuntu i can only see 2 partitions C and F. Partition D is not showing up in my ubuntu.

i have all my medias in thet partitions so if i wanna hear a music i have to log in to windows :(

Please help.

Comment: Install ntfs-3g

Comment: @smartboyhw Dear, I already wrote answer but it took sometime to arrive

Comment: Just for clarification - What do you mean by detect? `Not able to see in nautilus` or `not present in /media` or what?

Comment: @K.KPatel OK sorry:P

Comment: Try opening "Disk Utility" and see if you can mount the partition from there. Modify your question accordingly for a more useful answer.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount` to your question, that will help us check the type of partitions and if they are already mounted somewhere in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You should install ntfs-3g, Install it using this command in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: I think it is already installed by default.